# jQuery animation delay not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am animating a div when a user hovers over and just wanted a bit of a delay on it but it doesn't seem to add the delay in, is there something i'm doing wrong?

```
$(".carousel-desc").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({ 'height': '180px' }, { queue: false, duration: 600 });
});

$(".carousel-desc").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({ 'height': '40px' }, { queue: false, duration: 600 });
});
```

Thanks, J.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is `queue: false;` Usally your animation get queued, but you let the animate-function animate immediately.

Maybe this will do what you propably need:

```
$("#element").mouseEnter(function(){
   $("#element").clearQueue();
   //other stuff
}
```

for your stuff:

```
$(".carousel-desc").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).clearQueue();
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({ 'height': '180px' }, { duration: 600 });
});

$(".carousel-desc").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).clearQueue();
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({ 'height': '40px' }, { duration: 600 });
});
```

Comment: well, my code does work if i take the 'queue' out, but the delay doesn't work if I add your code in with the queue:false in there.

Comment: sorry, forgot to remove the queue:false :) Will change

Answer (score 2):

[.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) delays an animation queue

since you put `queue: false` in your animation options, it is executed immediately.

use it like this and it will be fixed

```
$(".carousel-desc").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({ 'height': '180px' }, { duration: 600 });
});

$(".carousel-desc").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({ 'height': '40px' }, { duration: 600 });
});
```

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hxfGg/

Comment: but now it queues the animation, so if people hover over and out a few times it does the animation

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Snicksie, however, for your current case of code, there is a better approach:

```
$('.carousel-desc').hover(function () {
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({
        'height': '180px'
    }, 600);
}, function () {
    $(this).delay(1000).animate({
         'height': '40px'
     }, 600);
});
```

<sup>**[ [View output](http://%24%28%27.carousel-desc%27%29.hover%28function%20%28%29%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%24%28this%29.delay%281000%29.animate%28%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27height%27%3a%20%27180px%27%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20600%29;%20%7D,%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%24%28this%29.delay%281000%29.animate%28%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%27height%27%3a%20%2740px%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D,%20600%29;%20%7D%29;) ]**</sup>